# Replace select result_id with name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I do have 2 tables like so:

```
____________________________________________________
|categories_id|categories_name|categories_description|
```

and

```
__________________________________________
|categories_id|img_link|parent_id|
```

and some other columns that are irrelevant
 I would like it to display in this kind of manner:

```
id|categories_name|parent_id|img_link
```

This is what I came up with so far...

```
SELECT  '' as 'id', c.categories_id, cd.categories_name as 'Name', c.parent_id as 'Parent Category', concat('http://www.url.com/images/',c.categories_image) as 'Image URL'
FROM categories c, categories_description cd
WHERE c.categories_id=cd.categories_id
GROUP BY c.categories_id;
```

Which got me to this kind of thing:

```
id|categories_name|parent_id|img_link
```

I've tried to left join it somehow but without success.

```
SELECT c.categories_id, '' AS 'id', cd.categories_name AS 'Name', c.parent_id AS 'Parent Category', concat('http://www.url.com/images/',c.categories_image) AS 'Image URL'
FROM categories_description cd
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.parent_id = cd.categories_name
WHERE c.categories_id=cd.categories_id AND language_id=1
GROUP BY c.categories_id;
```

This returns zeros in the Parent Category column. The question is, how can I replace `parent_id` in this select with `categories_name` where `parent_id=categories_id`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second query, you're joining on c.parent_id = cd.category_name rather than c.parent_id = cd.parent_id.

Comment: So, now I'm using  
`SELECT DISTINCT c.categories_id, '' AS 'id', cd.categories_id AS 'Name', cd.categories_name AS 'Parent Category', concat('http://www.url.com/images/',c.categories_image) AS 'Image URL'
FROM categories_description cd
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.parent_id = cd.categories_id
where language_id=1 group by c.categories_id;`
  
It now repleces `parent_id' with `categories_name` but it also doesn't replace `categories_id` with `categories_name`

Comment: When joining, you need to be join on like/matching columns.

    `SELECT DISTINCT c.categories_id, '' AS 'id', cd.categories_id AS 'Name', cd.categories_name AS 'Parent Category', concat('http://www.url.com/images/',c.categories_image) AS 'Image URL' 
FROM categories_description cd 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.parent_id = cd.categories_id 
where language_id=1 group by c.categories_id;`

Matches on c.parent_id = cd.categories_id, but they are not the same.

Instead, you want  c.categories_id = cd.categories_id because that is the common thread/foreign key between the two tables.